# JQuery sortable table with child rows - is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently displaying data about customers in a sortable table using JQuery. It's not a problem to allow the dragging and dropping of rows in the table. However, the challenge is that I have code in place to allow a row to expand and show the [non-sortable] child rows. After child rows are visible in the table, it is still possible to drag and drop the parent in a different location, but of course the child-rows stay where they are!

I've created an example in JSFiddle to clarify the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/GMUbj/65/

Note: table rows that have "sub-row" in the class, are child elements, and rows that have a class of "toSort" are sortable parent rows.

In the above example, "Business Analysis" and "Project Manager" are parent rows that have both been expanded, their children are visible. It is possible to drag and drop those rows (it's quirky, and you might have to try a few times, but it does work!).

I've tried numerous new approaches to try and remedy this, including using div and span to try and group my  elements. The behavior I'm after is something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/PM6nv/16/

.. and I've tried to alter my code to do something like what we have above in the unordered lists, but it usually breaks the table sorting ability.

Comment: you should $.detatch the child elements then reattach them after the parent is placed.

Comment: Thanks Autosponge. Although I'm not so sure how I can do that because technically the child elements aren't really child elements, they are just other <tr> items in the table.  Perhaps you think I should [if an item is dragged] try and go down through my html, and if a <tr> element has class "sub-row", then detach it(as it's a child). Then reattach it upon a re draw?